# Stream PDF Byte array from WebAPI to browser

Tags: pdf, browser, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I'm working in C#.net in a WebAPI...

I have...
WebAPI Controller...

```
public class GetSMBController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage GET(int AgencyID, string UserName)
    {
        var Pdfs = new HttpResponseMessage();

        Pdfs = Utilities.Reporting.CreateStandardMapBooklet(AgencyID,UserName);

        return Pdfs;
    }

}
```

That calls a method...

```
 public static HttpResponseMessage CreateStandardMapBooklet(int AgencyID, string userName)
    {
        string baseDataPath = @"\\dvfmweb4\\arcgisserver\basedata\";
        string tempDataPath = @"\\dvfmweb4\arcgisserver\tempGrowerData\";
        string unitTestSession = "UnitTestSession";
        int ShadeType = 1;
        bool isInImagery = false;
        double MaxSceneSize = 1.5;
        bool ScaleBar = true;
        int MapSettingID = 0;
        bool OverallPage = false;
        bool OverallImagery = false;
        bool IsRecordKeepingSheet = false;
        int RecordKeepingSheetID = 0;
        int TemplateID = 1480;



        RCIS.Mapping.MapDomain.Reports.StandardMapBookletReport _Pdfs = new RCIS.Mapping.MapDomain.Reports.StandardMapBookletReport(
                                                                                baseDataPath,
                                                                                tempDataPath,
                                                                                unitTestSession,
                                                                                AgencyID,
                                                                                ShadeType,
                                                                                isInImagery,
                                                                                MaxSceneSize,
                                                                                ScaleBar,
                                                                                MapSettingID,
                                                                                TemplateID,
                                                                                OverallPage,
                                                                                OverallImagery,
                                                                                false,
                                                                                RecordKeepingSheetID,
                                                                                userName,
                                                                                true);
        PDF testPDF = new PDF();
        byte[] test = null;
        try
        {
            List<RCIS.Mapping.MapDomain.Layout.CreatePdfResponse> pdf = _Pdfs.CreateReports();

            foreach (var item in pdf)
            {
                //PDFInfo info = new PDFInfo();
                //info.PdfBytes = item.PdfBytes;
                testPDF.Report = item.PdfBytes;
                test = item.PdfBytes;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(test)
        };
        response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(test);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline")
        {
            FileName = String.Format(AgencyID + userName + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMddyyyy_HHmmss"))

        };

        response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue()
        {
            MaxAge = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60) // Cache for 30s so IE8 can open the PDF
        };





        return response;

    }
```

Sorry for some of the commented out stuff and goofy variable names...I'm just trying to see if this is a viable thing.

the test object and HttpResponse message Content ARE populated but
I'm receiving this error when I call this from a browser...

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

An error has occurred.

Value cannot be null. Parameter name: content

System.ArgumentNullException

at System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent..ctor(Byte[] content) at MappingServicesWebAPI.Utilities.Reporting.CreateStandardMapBooklet(Int32 AgencyID, String userName) in d:\FarmMaps\Web\WebAPI\MappingServicesWebAPI\MappingServicesWebAPI\Utilities\Reporting.cs:line 92 at MappingServicesWebAPI.Controllers.GetSMBController.GET(Int32 AgencyID, String UserName) in d:\FarmMaps\Web\WebAPI\MappingServicesWebAPI\MappingServicesWebAPI\Controllers\MappingController.cs:line 143 at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__4() at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: Based on the exception the value for `test` is null when you are supplying it to byte array content...also your code is not clear, especially the foreach loop and assigning bytes to `test`

Comment: Thanks for the response...I did already put this statement in "Sorry for some of the commented out stuff and goofy variable names...I'm just trying to see if this is a viable thing."  I thought this would cover the "unclear code"...test is definitely populated, that's the first thing I checked, i wouldn't post a question unless I am at the end of my rope.

Comment: ???..well, the stack trace clearly indicates that the exception is being thrown because the supplied content to ByteArrayContent is null...

Comment: Turns out the the byte array is too big to send across the wire with the default settings